# What is wrong with my novel LCS algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to independently derive the dynamic programming solution to the LCS problem.

Consider the following two strings:

`Q=BAT
P=ABACD`

Let's first note that the LCS is still the same as we slide along ONE of the strings. That is, it is easy to see that

LCS(BAT, ABAC) = LCS(BAT, ABACD)

This makes me think that we could have build optimal solutions based on a single pointer that slides on each character of the second string.

That is, we build up the subsolutions like:

That is, we want to slide across the string P.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def LCS(Q, P): 
    subsolution_table = defaultdict(lambda: "")
    for i in xrange(len(P)):
        last_solution_with_char = LCS(Q, P[:i - 1]) + P[i]
        if is_subsequence(last_solution_with_char, Q):
            return last_solution_with_char
        else: 
            # Reuse last solution
            return LCS(Q, P[:i - 1])
```

I'm stuck here. I don't know how to get to the actual solution to the LCS problem. This is effectively an O(N^2) solution due to the linear scan and the `is_subsequence` check.

But I'm not sure how to get to the right suboptimal solution from my current logic.

Any advice on this would be amazing.

Comment: I can't follow what you're trying to do in that code.  There's no base case.  The code returns on the first iteration of `i`, albeit with possible recursion, but the forced `return` renders the loop ineffective.  There's no base definition for `last_solution_with_char`, and `subsolution_table` isn't used.  With this many unknowns, I don't have enough information to apply your general description of "slide along the strings".

Comment: Please describe your algorithm (or idea) in words.

Comment: Updated accoridngly. Let me know if you guys need more info